# View height is getting changed after rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My webview shows webpage that contains video. This webview contains navigation bar and statusbar.

The problem is that after watching videos in landscape mode and coming back to webview, the view height gets changed. And none of any methods of webview are getting invoked at that time.

It works fine in portrait mode watching.

Here are some screenshots of the views:

---

### Before watching video / after watching video in portrait rotation

[image]

---

### After watching video in landscape rotation

[image]

Why does that happen?

Comment: set autoresizing masks correctly, because I tried it & works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to Add this line after watching the video..

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

**UPDATE:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(update:) name:@"MPAVControllerPlaybackStateChangedNotification" object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(update:) name:@"MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted" object:nil];
}
```

and the update method is bellow...

```
#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark NSNotification Action

- (void)update:(NSNotification *)n {
    NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   Str Key ===>>%@",[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]);

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n>>>>>>>>>>> Updateing  >> %@ >>>>>>>>\n\n",[n description]);

    if ([[[n userInfo]objectForKey:@"MPAVControllerNewStateParameter"] intValue] == 0) {
        NSLog(@">>>>>>  1111111111111111111111111111111111111");
    }
    /*
     >>>>>>>>>>> Updateing  >> NSConcreteNotification 0x9c85740 {name = MPAVControllerPlaybackStateChangedNotification; object = <MPAVController: 0x6770010>; userInfo = {
     MPAVControllerNewStateParameter = 1;
     MPAVControllerOldStateParameter = 2;
     }}>>>>>>>>
     */

    if ([[[n userInfo]objectForKey:@"MPAVControllerNewStateParameter"] intValue] == 1 && [[[n userInfo]objectForKey:@"MPAVControllerOldStateParameter"] intValue] == 2  ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
        //[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    }


}
```

Comment: ok i think you use HTML5Page for it?? and see try my updated code...

Comment: @rohanpanchal hey just see the code just try it and use some extra feature like set orientation in potrait after seen the video etc from my code.... it just extra info.. hope this helpful to you..

Comment: no this is not error but its not respond to UIDevice after the iOS 4.3 i think from that version but just comment it and try after that ... its not imp...

Comment: @rohanpanchal i add the line which required to add in another condition dude now i add this line see dude and then try it...

Comment: you open this vedio from HTML with webview ??

Comment: and also you add the line which i add after some time ??? i just forgot to add it bcoz i post before on top so.. you try with new one..??

Comment: ya i have added line of "Statusbar" as you suggested , but it still not working

Comment: i dont know which class or code you use for display the vedio but i know that if you set that line where your stop or finished the vedio and comeback from that view then i am sure its working sure... and also try this line add in viewwillAppear method in your this class and just try to go back and re-enter in that class, you will see the perfact view..

Comment: sorry,your code is not working.

Comment: ok dude i try something change in my code, and i use HTML% in webview which from i display the video and its working fine but here you use something else so its not working , so i will post if i got... :)

Comment: Rather than, setstatusBar hidden in condition, I set the Frame for navigation Bar LIKE: self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44);  Thanks for Your REPLY!!

Answer (score 0):

The way I have managed to fix it is really simple, basically the core of the problem if this : When you rotate the view and the NavigationController recalculates its new position, it thinks it should be at the top of the window because the status bar is hidden. When you show both the status bar and the navigation bar after that, they are overlapping.

The way to fix this is really easy, simply keep a BOOL to remember if your overlay is shown or hidden, and implement both willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation in your ViewController.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (!isOverlayShowing)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    }
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (!isOverlayShowing)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    }
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

By quickly showing and hiding the StatusBar in these two methods, the StatusBar is shown at the exact moment the NavigationBar recalculates its position. I don't know if this is the best implementaiton to fix this problem, but so far this method works and does not create any flickering on screen and is very smooth.

Comment: but where to set the Bool variable.

Comment: Put it in your ViewController.m It should work fine.